# python.lib or python.a or a python.wasm static library usable for nodejs

Tags: python, php, ruby, perl

Is there a way I can use a `python.lib` or `python.a` or a `python.wasm` static library usable into nodejs extension to be used as imports? I am looking for such for other interpretors like `ruby`, `php`, `perl`, `rust` as well.

Comment: `cpython` support for wasm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cowasm/py-cython for python pip support https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cowasm/python-pip

Comment: `php` support for wasm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@php-wasm/node

Comment: `ruby` support for wasm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ruby-head-wasm-wasi

Comment: `perl` support for wasm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chriskoch/perl-wasm

Comment: some text on java wasm runtime not tried out https://github.com/mirkosertic/Bytecoder https://www.infoworld.com/article/3692456/hands-on-with-java-and-wasm.html

Comment: some text on c# wasm runtime not tried out https://www.fermyon.com/blog/dotnet-wasi

Comment: some text on java wasm runtime not tried out https://github.com/jtulach/bck2brwsr

Answer (score 1):

With some effort, I could search for `wasm` support for `interpreted languages` of `php`, `perl`, `python`, `ruby`. I have made it a package just a few minutes back now after the close request since I needed it and intend to keep it updated in near future for versions. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bridge-wasm . The dependencies are these
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bridge-wasm?activeTab=dependencies. However, I intend to maintain different versions of interpreters in different packages.

Use it based on need. I intend to have bifurate based on different languages and relevant versions sooner. Cheers.